# How to use tail() in combination with if condition?

Tags: r

I get an error using the `tail()` function which I dont fully understand. I would like to print the plot when the last row is greater then 0 else print `Have a nice day`
Data:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2015-02-13"), as.Date("2015-02-22"), by = "days")
b <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,0)
c <- c(20,30,26,20,30,40,5,10,4,0)
d <- c(11,2233,12,2,22,13,23,23,100,0)
df <- data.frame(dates,b,c,d)

a.plot<-plot(df)


test <- function(df) { 
  if(tail(df[2:ncol(df)], 1) > 0) { # check only last date

    return(a.plot)

  } else {

    print("Have a nice day!")

  }

}

test(df)
```

The error:

```
[1] "Have a nice day!"
Warning message:
In if (tail(df[2:ncol(df)], 1) > 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: `df[2:ncol(df)]` is still a dataframe of dim 10*3 so `tail` is a vector so it only checks if the first element in the vector is > 0. Use `tail(df$b,1)` for instance or `tail(df[,2],1)`

Comment: Hi etienne, thank you! Is there a way to adjust that for `df` rather then for the first vector?

Comment: in your df example which number do you want to check ? The whole row ? A specific column ?

Comment: Yes, just the last row of the data frame

Comment: If you want to check if the last value of `b` (for example) is greater than 0 use `tail(df$b,1)>0`. If you want all (resp at least one) value of the last row > 0 use `all(tail(df[,2:4]),1)>0` or `any`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use nrow on top of your tail. I also made the return create the plot instead of relying on a value outside of the function

See function below:

```
test <- function(df) { 
  if(sum(tail(df[2:ncol(df)], 1)) > 0) { # check only last date

    return(plot(df))

  } else {

    print("Have a nice day!")

  }

}
```

Comment: Hi phiver, thank you for that suggestion. But your code plots the graph rather printing `Have a nice day!` .The last row are zeros